# Data Extension - Define Send Relationship

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, send-email

i'm creating a sendable data extension for creating a journey for sending order confirmation to clients and the primary key of this DE is the OrderID. 
Is it correct if I select as Send relationship the ID --> Subscriber key? 
Thanks so much for helping
G.

Comment: Is this Data Extension sendable, does it hold email addresses? Or do you just use it for lookups in the email? Either way, Order ID is not the way to go - you need to use the unique identifier you have for your subscribers, like Subscriber Key

Answer (score 1):

"Send Relationship" in a data Extension can be understood as the answer to this question:

"In this Data Extension, which field defines the **person** that is being sent to?".

The "person" relates to what Marketing Cloud calls the Subscriber Key.
So likely, this is the correct answer for your question.

The Send Relationship does NOT necessarily have to be the Primary Key of the sending Data Extension, although in many cases, it might be.
In your case, it clearly isn't, as an order is not a Person.

==

Why is this important?

A person is used to e.g.:

- Gather sendout statistics on
- manage subscriptions and consent
- segment and target

... you get the idea. 
If you want to target *people*, you do not manage consent for orders.

==

What actually happens when you make SubscriberKey the "Send Relationship" field?
For clarity's sake, let us assume from now, you used "SubscriberKey" for this purpose.

At the time of sendout, the value of "Your record's SubscriberKey" is checked against All Subscribers List.
Essentially Marketing Cloud checks if it already knows this Person.
If no record with this value exists yet, a record on All Subscribers List is created with Subscriberkey = "Your record's SubscriberKey" and Status "Active".

If there already is a record with Status "unsubscribed" or "Held", the default Unsubscription and Bounce Management come into play here and could filter the person out of your sendout, depending on the All Subscribers List "Status" of the SubscriberKey (unsubscriptions are only respected in Commercial Sendouts).

From this moment of sendout on:

- Your Subscriber Key is on All Subscribers.
- Consequently, it also goes onto All Contacts. Which is not the same but has a larger scope. For example, People that come in through the Marketing Cloud Connector as Leads, Contacts or Users are considered Contacts even before you first send to them.
- Consequently, your Subscriber Key counts against your billable Contact Record Count

Each SubscriberKey can only become one contact.
So you should be ensuring that Send Relationship uses a UNIQUE identifier, or you will create duplicates that eventually cost money, and have more detrimental effects.
Obviously it is also not good if several people somehow get the same field value in Send Relationship, you will get weird information mixtures.

What information?

The value of the field you use in Send Relationship also is entered into the statistics gathered in the backend for the Sendout (>data views). You likely want statistics on a person by person level, see above.

The SubscriberKey goes into all sorts of statistics, so you do typically NOT want Email address (a personally identifiable data point) as the field in Send Relationship, which can pose a needless risk and potential GDPR problem, if you lose track of where personally identifiable data has gone in your system and can no longer remove it.

==

Sidenote:
The value of the field you use in Send Relationship also becomes a pretty useful "Personalization String" which can be used in emails, cloudpages etc. to establish the context of the "current user" for personalization purposes.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5

Using the personalization strings ONLY works if your person is on All Subscribers, so from the second of the first sendout onwards.
If you have never sent to a person, the personalization string does not work. Until you actually send. So happy testing :)

Hope this sheds some light!