# Beginners question about Send Relationship

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, email-studio, subscriber-key

I'm studying for the certification for email specialist but slightly confused by send relationship and how this is defined. I've always been under the impression that Subscriber key = Contact key.

For example, if I was to do a manual import to a DE containing first name, last name, email and have email as unique identifier and it contains list of people who are both new and existing in All Subscriber table. When I create DE and have the send relationship, I put it as email relates to subscribers on Subscriber Key

1. Will it now check whether this email address exists in the All Subscriber table (under email attribute, not subscriber key) and tries to match it or will it try to match Subscriber Key instead?
2. If it's later, doesn't that mean if a user has proper subscriber key (e.g. subkey1234) but we are trying to match email with this subscriber key? it won't find it?
3. Obviously the recommendation is to not have Email = Subscriber Key so will this mean if it doesn't exist, it will add this Email Field as Subscriber Key (i.e. these subscriber will have email as their subscriber key)?

I'm confused by how this all works so would be good if someone can explain more in layman's term.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I've tried to explain that here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306600/data-extension-define-send-relationship/306614#306614 , here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/367584/mc-journey-rowcount-and-lookup-function-help-please/367590#367590 and here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331499/how-to-choose-the-fields-for-a-send-relationship-in-marketing-cloud/331555#331555