SFMC Send Relationship: SendableDataExtensionField and SendableSubscriberField
We are trying to get our heads around the send relationships in SFMC. We understand that in a sendable data extension we need a key (Subscriber Key) that uniquely identifies the individual being sent to. We have created a concatenated field in our data for this.
We also understand that this Subscriber Key is used in creating / updating entries in All Subscribers table. So far so good.
The question is about the relationship referenced in the user interface as [somefield] relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key. What should [somefield] be in this example? Is it the primary key of the sendable data extension, or something else?
Appreciate any help.

try these three :)
1)
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331499/how-to-choose-the-fields-for-a-send-relationship-in-marketing-cloud/331555#331555
2)
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306600/data-extension-define-send-relationship/306614#306614
3)
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/367584/mc-journey-rowcount-and-lookup-function-help-please/367590#367590

@JonasLamberty - are you confident about the author of these answers you are referring to? ;-)

John, you should be careful with creating your own subscriber key. "We have created a concatenated field in our data for this" might not be your best option. I will indeed suggest you familiarising with the links shared by Jonas, but also this article explaining what to consider when choosing the subscriber key in SFMC.
